# Using NFC in a webapp

Tags: java, javascript, applet, nfc

I have written a webbased application which handles contacts, orders, and permits to use this company's facilities.  We use an ACR122U interfacing with it via a Java Applet and javascript (http://ndefeditor.grundid.de/).

I have come to realize this was a bad idea, as it seems every week Firefox blocks the applet because 1.) it's an applet 2.) it's unsigned  3.)  Java needs to be updated

So I'm looking for a better way to interface with the ACR122U connected to each terminal via javascript.

One idea I had was to write a chrome app wrapper for my app, but I don't know if this will give me the access to the ACR122U that I need without using the applet.  There's a whole Java library (https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) that is available also.

Looking for any suggestions or anyone else with previous experience.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution

Comment: Not really what you are looking in the short-term, but there is the [Web NFC API](https://w3c.github.io/nfc/proposals/common/nfc.html) which is usable on [Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NFC_API/Using_the_NFC_API).